# What part of SSH forwarding sets up SSH_AUTH_SOCK?

Tags: ssh, forwarding, ssh-agent

I'm trying to get SSH agent forwarding working from my Mac to a Debian server. On my Mac, I have verified that I have:

- `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` exists
- `ssh-add -l` shows my identities
- `./ssh/config` has settings to enable ForwardAgent

Passwordless login to the remote server works fine. However, none of my identities are available there and the SSH_AUTH_SOCK is empty.

I'd like to understand how this gets set up in the remote environment, and what am I missing to make it work?

Update:

My server is set up with `AllowAgentForwarding=yes` in sshd_config and `ForwardAgent=yes` in ssh_config.

I found some tutorials that suggest running ``` eval ``ssh-agent ```, so I tried that but I suspect this is meant for the client machine. This did set up a SSH_AUTH_SOCK when I ran it on my server, but it doesn't seem to connect back to the client agent, and it says "The agent has no identities".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Mac with OS 10.6.x I found that agent forwarding didn't work until I added my key to the Apple keychain, with the following:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

where `~/.ssh/id_rsa` contains my private ssh key

I've a blog entry about [setting up ssh host configuration entries to simplify ssh command-lines](http://www.nickager.com/blog/simplifyingSSHCommandLines/) that may be of interest

Comment: Thanks, I had figured it out a while back: your answer is the correct solution on a Mac client.

Answer (score 2):

The server also has to enable agent forwarding.

Comment: I've tried setting `AllowAgentForwarding yes` in sshd_config and restarting ssh on the server. I still get the error _"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"_ when I try to do anything from the server.

Answer (score 1):

The client that runs the agent needs to have agent forwarding enabled. Not the server.

Never enable it globally, but on a per-host basis in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host myserver.foo.local
ForwardAgent yes
```

Or use the -A option when connecting:

```
ssh -A myserver.foo.local
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I already have my .ssh/config configured this way. I see SSH_AUTH_SOCK on my end, but not inside the SSH session. I was trying to understand what part of the client/server environment is responsible for setting up that socket, since I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Does the client show in verbose mode that it is requesting agent forwarding? ssh -vvv -A myserver.foo.local true 2>&1 | grep agent